# Method 'ThisWorkbook' of object '_Global' failed

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to copy the Mail's subject, sendername, date of the email from the PST mailbox to the excel workbook.
Here's the code I have so far :

```
Option Explicit
Sub Download_Outlook_Mail_To_Excel()
Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim sFolders As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim iRow As Integer, oRow As Integer
Dim MailBoxName As String, Pst_Folder_Name  As String


MailBoxName = "Backupmailbox"


Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox1" 'Sample "Inbox" or "Sent Items"

'To directly a Folder at a high level
'Set Folder = Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name)

'To access a main folder or a subfolder (level-1)
For Each Folder In Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders
    If VBA.UCase(Folder.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then GoTo Label_Folder_Found
    For Each sFolders In Folder.Folders
        If VBA.UCase(sFolders.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then
            Set Folder = sFolders
            GoTo Label_Folder_Found
        End If
    Next sFolders
Next Folder

Label_Folder_Found:
 If Folder.Name = "" Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Data in Input"
    GoTo End_Lbl1:
End If

'Read Through each Mail and export the details to Excel for Email Archival
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
Folder.Items.Sort "Received"

'Insert Column Headers
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = "Sender"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2) = "Subject"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3) = "Date"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4) = "Size"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 5) = "EmailID"
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 6) = "Body"

'Export eMail Data from PST Folder
oRow = 1
For iRow = 1 To Folder.Items.Count
    'If condition to import mails received in last 60 days
    'To import all emails, comment or remove this IF condition
    If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime) <= 60 Then
       oRow = oRow + 1
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1).Select
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderName
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 2) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 3) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 4) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Size
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 5) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailAddress
       'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 6) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Body
    End If
Next iRow
MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"
Set Folder = Nothing
Set sFolders = Nothing

End_Lbl1:
End Sub
```

When I run the code I get the

> "method of range of object _ Global Failed"

from the statement `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate`

I have enabled Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library reference, since the code is executed from outlook application.

Does anyone know what this error means and how can I fix it ?

Comment: You need to grab the instance of Excel that's (presumably) already open, and then qualify the workbook reference with an application object. Alternatively, create a new instance of Excel and open the workbook through that instance setting a reference to it.

Comment: As said @MacroMan, the issue is probably that your code is in Outlook and cannot detect which workbook you are trying to use.

Comment: Thanks @Macro Man, Since I already tried and failed with the referencing the Excel application object,  could you please confirm where the changes to be done in the code with Excel.application object, will change the code accordingly.

Comment: @lifeinvba Is the workbook already open when you run this code - or do you want to open the workbook with the code?

Comment: @R3uK thanks for the update,since am facing this issue for the first time, if you can modify the code and assist me it would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @Macro Man well I open the excel file and then run the code. If you can tweak the code to make the excel open that will also help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a couple of quick tweaks, try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Download_Outlook_Mail_To_Excel()
Dim Folder          As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim sFolders        As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim iRow            As Integer
Dim oRow            As Integer
Dim MailBoxName     As String
Dim Pst_Folder_Name As String

Const xlWorkbookName As String = "C:\Users\MacroMan\MyWorkbook.xlsx" '// change as required

'// I'm using late binding in case you don't actually have a reference set.
Dim xlApp           As Object
Dim xlWB            As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = False

Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlWorkbookName)

MailBoxName = "Backupmailbox"


Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox1" 'Sample "Inbox" or "Sent Items"

'To directly a Folder at a high level
'Set Folder = Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name)

'To access a main folder or a subfolder (level-1)
For Each Folder In Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders
    If VBA.UCase(Folder.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then GoTo Label_Folder_Found
    For Each sFolders In Folder.Folders
        If VBA.UCase(sFolders.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then
            Set Folder = sFolders
            GoTo Label_Folder_Found
        End If
    Next sFolders
Next Folder

Label_Folder_Found:
 If Folder.Name = "" Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Data in Input"
    GoTo End_Lbl1:
End If

'Read Through each Mail and export the details to Excel for Email Archival
xlWB.Sheets(1).Activate
Folder.Items.Sort "Received"

'Insert Column Headers
xlWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = "Sender"
xlWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2) = "Subject"
xlWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3) = "Date"
xlWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4) = "Size"
xlWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 5) = "EmailID"
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 6) = "Body"

'Export eMail Data from PST Folder
oRow = 1
For iRow = 1 To Folder.Items.Count
    'If condition to import mails received in last 60 days
    'To import all emails, comment or remove this IF condition
    If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime) <= 60 Then
       oRow = oRow + 1
       xlWB.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1).Select
       xlWB.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderName
       xlWB.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 2) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
       xlWB.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 3) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime
       xlWB.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 4) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Size
       xlWB.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 5) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailAddress
       'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 6) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Body
    End If
Next iRow
MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"
Set Folder = Nothing
Set sFolders = Nothing

xlWB.Close False
Set xlWB = Nothing

xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing

End_Lbl1:
End Sub
```

This will open the workbook for you, so no need to do so before hand